# additional javascript code on clientside after validation is suceeded

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have a button that causes validation. This is Required Field Validation (thus it is also done on client side and for double check is checked on serverside using `Page.IsValid`).

The question is: 
- how to do some additional javascript code on client side if validation is success?

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" ValidationGroup="Step1" CausesValidation="true" ID="step1Btn" OnClick="Step1Btn_ServerClick" class="btn btn-small btn-success" Text="Save &amp; Next Step" />
```

Basically I need to switch tabs if input is validated.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **Page_ClientValidate** built in function

eg

```
// Step1 -> validation group name
if (Page_ClientValidate("Step1"))
{
// move to other tab
}
```